# How to use Matlab to draw a ellipsoid

Tags: matlab

I could use this method to draw a ellipsoid in Matlab:
Xc is x-coordinate of the center, Xr is half the length of ellipsoid in x direction

```
Xc = 0; Xr = 1;
Yc = 0; Yr = 2;
Zc = 0; Zr = 3;

[X Y Z] = ellipsoid(Xc, Yc, Zc, Xr, Yr, Zr);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

This can give me a 3-D image of the ellipsoid but if I do not know things like Xc or Xr ..., all I know is a function:

```
A = 5; B = 0; C =2;
D = 2; E = 1;

P = [A B;
     B C];

q = [D E];

syms x y;

f = [x y] * P * [x y]' + q * [x y] + 1;
```

But it seems that surf won't allow to use syms variables.
ezplot(f) give only a 2-D ellipse.

How can I draw a 3-D ellipsoid with this function in Matlab using surf, mesh or anything else?

The reason I write this function f is that I want to see how the positive definiteness and negative definiteness of matrix P influence the image of function f.

Thanks!

Comment: How about `ezsurf`, `ezplot3`, etc.?

Comment: Thanks, but I finally used the method the guy said below. It was quite useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw an ellipsoid (or any other implicit surface) using [`isosurface`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html). For example, the ellipsoid 
`2*x^2+2xy+3y^2+2yz+4z^2+4z-1=0` can be drawn using the following code:

```
[x,y,z]= meshgrid(-2:0.05:2); % the surface should fit in the meshgrid area
v= 2*x.^2+2*x.*y+3*y.^2+2*y.*z+4*z.^2+4*z-1; % the left side of the equation
isosurface(x,y,z,v,0); % the value 0 is the right hand side of the equation
axis tight
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really a straight forward way to draw it.